# Help file in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms

I am working on a WPF App where i want to load the Help file when F1 is hit on the keyboard.

I am using the following syntax

**NotWorking**:System.windows.forms.help(null,@"myhelpfile.chm");

**Working**:System.windows.forms.help(null,@"C:\Data....\myhelpfile.chm");

So my question is i want to place  myhelpfile in a folder called FILES under solution explorer.

Any suggestions what should be my path ?

Comment: Have you tried `@"FILES/myhelpfile.chm"`

Answer (score 1):

Your working directory might have changed.  You can use **Application.StartupPath** to get the location of where you app was launched from.

So your code will change to:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp(null, Application.StartupPath + @"\Files\myhelpfile.com");
```

Comment: i am using the following syntax System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp(null,@"Files\myhelpfile.com"); –

Comment: Thanks for your time. Actual syntax which i mentioned in my question is working fine now.I will try the way you suggested also.

Answer (score 0):

Your URI path should start form your application work path, something like this:

```
System.windows.forms.help(null,@"FILES\myhelpfile.chm");
```

Comment: I am using the following syntax System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp(null,@"Files\myhelpfile.com");

Comment: system.windows.forms.help.showhelp is working.Thanks for your time.